# Windows Phone 8.1 - animate listview items

Tags: c#, listview, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I've got this piece of code that works just fine: when fired, the LstDevices ListView becomes transparent in 1 second.

```
    private void DoAnimation()
    {
        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

        doubleAnimation.To = 0;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, LstDevices);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");

        s.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        s.Begin();
    }
```

Fact is, I need this ListView to do 2 different things:

1) Animate the ListView so instead than becoming invisible, it should disappear by moving off screen.
2) Next step, if I swipe a single item, the single item should disappear by moving offscreen.

Fact is, I can't find the property that modifies the X and Y position of the items I need to move.
Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to do this by using a TranslateTransform with a DoubleAnimation.  You can change the X and Y values using the DoubleAnimation over time to give the appearance of moving offscreen.

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();     
itemToAnimate.RenderTransform = (Transform)new TranslateTransform();
```

And then when I have to set the target

```
Storyboard.SetTarget((Timeline)doubleAnimation, (DependencyObject)itemToAnimate.RenderTransform);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Please, can you provide a bit of code as an example?

Comment: Found the answer! I use this

  DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
  itemToAnimate.RenderTransform = (Transform)new TranslateTransform();

And then when I have to set the target

  Storyboard.SetTarget((Timeline)doubleAnimation, (DependencyObject)itemToAnimate.RenderTransform);

Comment: Glad to hear it, I was just about to work on this and found your answer.